# error: react state update on an unmounted component, not sure how to solve

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

So I am getting the error

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a 
useEffect cleanup function.
```

```
    const [loggedinUser, setLoggedInUser] = React.useState();
    db.ref("/activeUser").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const user = snapshot.val();       
        setLoggedInUser(snapshot.val());
    });
```

I think the call to setState inside the async code is causing this, but I can't setState elsewhere, I need it here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It might happen that the state is been set when component is unmount. Try using useEffect as below:

```
const [loggedinUser, setLoggedInUser] = React.useState();
useEffect(() => {
  let unmounted = false;

   const [loggedinUser, setLoggedInUser] = React.useState();
    db.ref("/activeUser").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        const user = snapshot.val();       
        !unmounted && setLoggedInUser(snapshot.val());
    });  

  return () => { unmounted = true };
}, []);
```